sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (sqlite3.IntegrityError) FOREIGN KEY constraint failed
I would like to have cascade deletion for a user and posts relationship.
models.py
class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    id: so.Mapped[int] = so.mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    username: so.Mapped[str] = so.mapped_column(sa.Unicode(32), index=True, unique=True)
    messages_sent: so.WriteOnlyMapped['Message'] = so.relationship(foreign_keys='Message.sender_id', back_populates='sender', cascade='all, delete', passive_deletes=True)
    messages_received: so.WriteOnlyMapped['Message'] = so.relationship(foreign_keys='Message.recipient_id', back_populates='recipient', cascade='all, delete', passive_deletes=True)
    posts: so.WriteOnlyMapped['Post'] = so.relationship(back_populates='author', cascade='all, delete', passive_deletes=True)


class Post(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'post'
    id: so.Mapped[int] = so.mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    body: so.Mapped[str] = so.mapped_column(sa.UnicodeText(4096))
    user_id: so.Mapped[int] = so.mapped_column(sa.ForeignKey('user.id', ondelete='CASCADE'), index=True)
    author: so.Mapped['User'] = so.relationship(back_populates='posts')
    photos: so.Mapped['Photo'] = so.relationship(back_populates='post', cascade='all, delete', passive_deletes=True)
    tags: so.Mapped[List['Tag']] = so.relationship(secondary=tags, back_populates='posts', cascade='all, delete', passive_deletes=True)
    comments: so.WriteOnlyMapped['Comment'] = so.relationship(back_populates='post', cascade='all, delete', passive_deletes=True)
    votes: so.WriteOnlyMapped['PostVote'] = so.relationship(back_populates='vote_post', cascade='all, delete', passive_deletes=True)
    flags: so.WriteOnlyMapped['Flag'] = so.relationship(back_populates='post', cascade='all, delete', passive_deletes=True)

class Message(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'message'
    id: so.Mapped[int] = so.mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    sender_id: so.Mapped[int] = so.mapped_column(sa.ForeignKey('user.id', ondelete='CASCADE'), index=True)
    sender: so.Mapped['User'] = so.relationship(foreign_keys='Message.sender_id', back_populates='messages_sent')
    recipient_id: so.Mapped[int] = so.mapped_column(sa.ForeignKey('user.id', ondelete='CASCADE'), index=True)
    recipient: so.Mapped['User'] = so.relationship(foreign_keys='Message.recipient_id', back_populates='messages_received')
    _body: so.Mapped[str] = so.mapped_column(sa.UnicodeText)

routes.py
routes.py
def delete(id):
    user = db.first_or_404(sa.select(User).where(User.id == id))
    db.session.execute(sa.text('PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON'))

    #db.session.execute(user.messages_sent.delete())      
    #db.session.execute(user.messages_received.delete()) 
    db.session.execute(user.posts.delete())

Error
sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (sqlite3.IntegrityError) FOREIGN KEY constraint failed
[SQL: DELETE FROM post WHERE ? = post.user_id]
[parameters: (6,)]

When I run user.messages_sent.delete() and user.messages_received.delete(), there are no errors.
I commented both lines and ran user.posts.delete(). The FOREIGN KEY constraint fails.
I tried adding foreign_keys to the User and Post model like so.
class User():
    ...
    posts: so.WriteOnlyMapped['Post'] = so.relationship(foreign_keys='Post.user_id', back_populates='author', cascade='all, delete', passive_deletes=True)


class Post():
   ...
   author: so.Mapped['User'] = so.relationship(foreign_keys='Post.user_id', back_populates='posts')   

It returns the same error. I'm not sure what's causing the foreign key constraint to fail or if a constraint in another model is failing.
